# Why is my class Paragraph not making a paragraph element <p>a</p> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code in JS:

```js
class Paragraph {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
    this.createParagraph();
  }
  createParagraph() {
    var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    var p = paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.text));
    return p;
  }
}

var a = new Paragraph("a"); // <p>a</p> This is the result I want, which I'm  not getting
console.dir(a);
```

I want to be able to create what I've described above through var a = new Paragraph("a"); but it isn't working, can anyone help out why?

Comment: Could you clarify the output you want? Do you want a `string`? A `Node`? An instance of your `Paragraph` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues. Firstly `createParagraph()` needs to return the `paragraph`, not `p` as that contains the *appended child element*, in this case that's the text node.

Secondly the constructor needs to return the `p` you created in `createParagraph()`. Try this:

```js
class Paragraph {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
    return this.createParagraph();
  }
  createParagraph() {
    var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.text));
    return paragraph;
  }
}

var newPara = new Paragraph("Lorem ipsum");
document.body.appendChild(newPara);
console.dir(newPara);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it, but I'm getting the following error when trying to execute document.body.appendChild(newPara); : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: You may have missed one of the return statements I added. If not, could you please show the full code you've got in a https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: thanks for the help, strangely I'm still getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

Comment: You've not called `insertBefore` in any of the code you've shown, so I can't really help with that other than to advise that you check whatever variable you're calling it on exists in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function according to this solution:

```
createParagraph() {
    const paragraph = document.createElement('p');
    document.body.append(paragraph);
    const p = paragraph.appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.text));
    return p;
    }
}
```

Also don't use `var`.

Comment: Syntax error aside, this returns the text node, not the `<p>` element.

Comment: Which you assumed that he wants the `<p>` in the first place.

Comment: It's in the question: `// <p>a</p> This is the result I want, which I'm  not getting`

Comment: Which is obviously way less than a HTMLParagraphElement.

Comment: Sure they explicitly stated `<p>` as a string, but it's not hard to extrapolate context from the code that's provided.